# How to fix my CRUD not working in Update PHP MSQL

Tags: php, html, sql

I tried to implement CRUD in m website but I am able to make Create, Read and Delete. However, something went wrong during developing the Update function. Can anyone help me? I will provide the code below.
The code is used to update the users information if the logged in person is an Admin. Thank you.

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $address = $status = $level = "";
$firstname_err = $lastname_err = $email_err = $address_err = $level_err = $status_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];

    // Validate name-first
    $input_firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
    if(empty($input_firstname)){
        $firstname_err = "Please enter a first name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_firstname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $firstname_err = "Please enter a valid first name.";
    } else{
        $firstname = $input_firstname;
    }

    //Validate lastname
    $input_lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
    if(empty($input_lastname)){
        $lastname_err = "Please enter a last name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_lastname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $lastname_err = "Please enter a valid last name.";
    } else{
        $lastname = $input_firstname;
    }

    //Validate email address
    $input_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    if(empty($input_email)){
        $email_err = "Please enter an email address.";
    } else{
        $email = $input_email;
    }

    // Validate address 
    $input_address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    if(empty($input_address)){
        $address_err = "Please enter an address.";
    } else{
        $address = $input_address;
    }

    // Validate access level
    $input_level = trim($_POST["level"]);
    if(empty($input_level)){
        $level_err = "Please enter an level.";
    } elseif($input_level == 'Admin'){
        $level = $input_level;
    }elseif($input_level == 'Customer'){
        $level = $input_level;
    }else{
        $level_err = 'Please choose from Admin or Customer';
    }

    // Validate status
    $input_status = trim($_POST["status"]);
    if(empty($input_status)){
        $status_err = "Please enter a status";
    }elseif($input_status == '1'){
        $status = $input_status;
    }elseif($input_status == '0'){
        $status = $input_status;
    }else{
        $status_err = "Please enter a valid status";
    }
    

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($firstname_err) && empty($lastname_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($level_err) && empty($status_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname=?, lastname=? address=?, email=?, access_level=?, status=? WHERE id=?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssii", $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_email, $param_address, $param_level, $param_status, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_firstname = $firstname;
            $param_lastname = $lastname;
            $param_address = $address;
            $param_email = $email;            
            $param_level = $level;
            $param_status = $status;
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }else{
            echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
                    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
                    $email = $row["email"];
                    $address = $row["address"];
                    $level = $row["access_level"];
                    $status = $row["status"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<?php
// core configuration
include_once "../../config/core.php";

// check if logged in as admin
include_once "../login_checker.php";

// set page title
$page_title = "Update Record";

// include page header HTML
include '../layout_head.php';

echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";

// get parameter values, and to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

// tell the user he's already logged in
if ($action == 'already_logged_in') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>You</strong> are already logged in.";
    echo "</div>";
} else if ($action == 'logged_in_as_admin') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>You</strong> are logged in as admin.";
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "</div>";

//content when logged in
?>
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Update Record</h2>
                </div>
                <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the record.</p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($firstname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $firstname_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($lastname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $lastname_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <textarea name="address" class="form-control"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $address_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($level_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Access Level</label>
                        <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $level; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $level_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($status_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $status; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $status_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are updating data, when if empty... not when if not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$firstname = $lastname = $email = $address = $status = $level = "";
$firstname_err = $lastname_err = $email_err = $address_err = $level_err = $status_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["id"])){
    // Get hidden input value
    $id = $_POST["id"];

    // Validate name-first
    $input_firstname = trim($_POST["firstname"]);
    if(empty($input_firstname)){
        $firstname_err = "Please enter a first name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_firstname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $firstname_err = "Please enter a valid first name.";
    } else{
        $firstname = $input_firstname;
    }

    //Validate lastname
    $input_lastname = trim($_POST["lastname"]);
    if(empty($input_lastname)){
        $lastname_err = "Please enter a last name.";
    } elseif(!filter_var($input_lastname, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/")))){
        $lastname_err = "Please enter a valid last name.";
    } else{
        $lastname = $input_firstname;
    }

    //Validate email address
    $input_email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    if(empty($input_email)){
        $email_err = "Please enter an email address.";
    } else{
        $email = $input_email;
    }

    // Validate address 
    $input_address = trim($_POST["address"]);
    if(empty($input_address)){
        $address_err = "Please enter an address.";
    } else{
        $address = $input_address;
    }

    // Validate access level
    $input_level = trim($_POST["level"]);
    if(empty($input_level)){
        $level_err = "Please enter an level.";
    } elseif($input_level == 'Admin'){
        $level = $input_level;
    }elseif($input_level == 'Customer'){
        $level = $input_level;
    }else{
        $level_err = 'Please choose from Admin or Customer';
    }

    // Validate status
    $input_status = trim($_POST["status"]);
    if(empty($input_status)){
        $status_err = "Please enter a status";
    }elseif($input_status == '1'){
        $status = $input_status;
    }elseif($input_status == '0'){
        $status = $input_status;
    }else{
        $status_err = "Please enter a valid status";
    }
    
    echo "<script>alert('";
    echo "Checking all inputs vales---"; 
    echo $id; echo "=id--<br>";
    echo $input_firstname; echo "=fname---<br>";
    echo $input_lastname; echo "=lname---<br>";
    echo $input_email; echo "=email---<br>";
    echo $input_address; echo "=add---<br>";
    echo $input_level; echo "=level<br>";
    echo $input_status; echo "=stat<br>";
    echo "')</script> ";
    

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($firstname_err) && empty($lastname_err) && empty($email_err) && empty($address_err) && empty($level_err) && empty($status_err)){
        // Prepare an update statement
            echo "<script>alert('";
            echo "Im inside `Check Inputs before inserting in database` If Block... All Good so far"; echo "<br>"; 
            echo "')</script> ";
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname=?, lastname=? address=?, email=?, access_level=?, status=? WHERE id=?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){
            echo "<script>alert('";
            echo "Im inside `mysqli_prepare` If Block... All Good so far"; echo "<br>"; 
            echo "')</script> ";
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssii", $param_firstname, $param_lastname, $param_address, $param_email, $param_level, $param_status, $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_firstname = $firstname;
            $param_lastname = $lastname;
            $param_address = $address;
            $param_email = $email;            
            $param_level = $level;
            $param_status = $status;
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                // Records updated successfully. Redirect to landing page
            echo "<script>alert('";
                echo "Im inside `mysqli_stmt_execute` If Block... All Good so far"; echo "<br>"; 
            echo "')</script> ";
                header("location: index.php");
                exit();
            } else{
            echo "<script>alert('";
                echo "Im inside `mysqli_stmt_execute` If Block... Not Good"; echo "<br>"; 
            echo "')</script> ";
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
            // Close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('";
            echo "Im directly into else block from `empty input check If` Block... Not Good"; echo "<br>"; 
            echo "')</script> ";
            echo mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
} else{
    // Check existence of id parameter before processing further
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["id"]))){
        // Get URL parameter
        $id =  trim($_GET["id"]);

        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?";
        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){

            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $param_id);

            // Set parameters
            $param_id = $id;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
                    /* Fetch result row as an associative array. Since the result set contains only one row, we don't need to use while loop */
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

                    // Retrieve individual field value
                    $firstname = $row["firstname"];
                    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
                    $email = $row["email"];
                    $address = $row["address"];
                    $level = $row["access_level"];
                    $status = $row["status"];
                } else{
                    // URL doesn't contain valid id. Redirect to error page
                    header("location: error.php");
                    exit();
                }

            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        // Close connection
        mysqli_close($link);
    }  else{
        // URL doesn't contain id parameter. Redirect to error page
        header("location: error.php");
        exit();
    }
}
?>

<?php
// core configuration
include_once "../../config/core.php";

// check if logged in as admin
include_once "../login_checker.php";

// set page title
$page_title = "Update Record";

// include page header HTML
include '../layout_head.php';

echo "<div class='col-md-12'>";

// get parameter values, and to prevent undefined index notice
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "";

// tell the user he's already logged in
if ($action == 'already_logged_in') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>You</strong> are already logged in.";
    echo "</div>";
} else if ($action == 'logged_in_as_admin') {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>";
    echo "<strong>You</strong> are logged in as admin.";
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "</div>";

//content when logged in
?>
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="page-header">
                    <h2>Update Record</h2>
                </div>
                <p>Please edit the input values and submit to update the record.</p>
                <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($firstname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $firstname; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $firstname_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($lastname_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $lastname_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $email_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($address_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Address</label>
                        <textarea name="address" class="form-control"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea>
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $address_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($level_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Access Level</label>
                        <input type="text" name="level" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $level; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $level_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($status_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                        <label>Status</label>
                        <input type="text" name="status" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $status; ?>">
                        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $status_err;?></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                    <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I updated the code please run that code.
I cannot guess more what else could be be wrong but i have added some echo to your code. please run it and find where is the error. Double check your bind_parameter type.they must be exactly same as your database table types. i only help you as giving u an example not the whole solution.

Now you can see the alert showing where are you so you can track down the problem

Hope it will help and solve your problem.

Comment: I had changed the ```if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql)){``` false message and the error is 





```Warning: mysqli_stmt_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt```

Comment: `sssi` inside `mysqli_stmt_bind_param(` means you are binding 3 strings and 1 integer. s for string, i for integer, b for boolean if any. Now Count how many $variables do you have and put 's' or 'i' depending on the type of varaible. and please go through the document. and Also the erro you are getting is because you did not pass the inside `mysqli_stmt_error()` like `mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)`.. Please update your code also your changes so i can review

Comment: [Mysqli Bind Param manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: i updated my answer. accept it if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks I finally found my problem, the sequence of the updating sql statement. I will provide the code below. Thanks for all your help. @Mohammed Bilal do you have any social networking account that I can contact you for further help if I face any problem. Still, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please accept my answer and remove your answer if i help you. Thanks and my skype-is @saif287430

Answer (score -1):

```
// javascript

  let itemdelete = document.querySelectorAll(".item-delete");

itemdelete.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            let url = btn.getAttribute("href");

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    } else {
                        alert("errorrr");
                    }
                })
        }
    })

})) 

//account 

using Anyar.Models;
using Anyar.ViewModels;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Anyar.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAdmin()
        {
            AppUser user = new AppUser
            {
                Fullname = "Kamil Qurbanov",
                UserName = "SuperAdminKamil"
            };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Kamil000");
            return Ok(result);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole()
        {
            IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole("SuperAdmin");
            IdentityRole role2 = new IdentityRole("Admin");
            IdentityRole role3 = new IdentityRole("Member");

            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role2);
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role3);

            return Ok("added");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> AddRole()
        {
            AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("SuperAdminKamil");
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");
            return Ok("added");
        }


        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel adminLogin)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }

            AppUser appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(adminLogin.Username);

            if (appUser == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "name or password is invalid");
                return View();
            }

            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(appUser, adminLogin.Password, false, false);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "name or password is invalid");
                return View();
            }


            return RedirectToAction("index","home");
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }

        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel register)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }

            AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(register.Username);

            if (user != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("username", "bele nir user name sitifade olunub");
                return View();
            }

            user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(register.Email);

            if (user != null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("email", "bele nir user email sitifade olunub");
                return View();
            }

            user = new AppUser
            {
                UserName = register.Username,
                Email = register.Email,
                Fullname = register.Fullname,
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                foreach (var err in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Description);
                    return View();
                }
            }

            var roleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member");

            if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
            {
                foreach (var err in roleresult.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Description);
                    return View();
                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("login", "account");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
  // pagination
public class PaginationList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public PaginationList(List<T> values,int count , int page , int pageSize)
        {
            AddRange(values);
            TotalPage = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
            Page= page; 
        }

        public int TotalPage { get; set; }
        public int Page { get; set; }
        public bool HasPreviuos { get => Page > 1; }
        public bool HasNextiuos { get => Page < TotalPage; }

        public static PaginationList<T> Craete(IQueryable<T> query , int page , int pageSize)
        {
            return new PaginationList<T>(query.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList(), query.Count(), page, pageSize); 
        }


    }  



// javascript
    
      let itemdelete = document.querySelectorAll(".item-delete");
    
    itemdelete.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                let url = btn.getAttribute("href");
    
                fetch(url)
                    .then(response => {
                        if (response.status == 200) {
                            window.location.reload(true);
                        } else {
                            alert("errorrr");
                        }
                    })
            }
        })
    
    })) 
    
    //account 
    
    using Anyar.Models;
    using Anyar.ViewModels;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    
    namespace Anyar.Controllers
    {
        public class AccountController : Controller
        {
            private readonly UserManager<AppUser> _userManager;
            private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
            private readonly SignInManager<AppUser> _signInManager;
    
            public AccountController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager)
            {
                _userManager = userManager;
                _roleManager = roleManager;
                _signInManager = signInManager;
            }
    
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAdmin()
            {
                AppUser user = new AppUser
                {
                    Fullname = "Kamil Qurbanov",
                    UserName = "SuperAdminKamil"
                };
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Kamil000");
                return Ok(result);
            }
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> CreateRole()
            {
                IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole("SuperAdmin");
                IdentityRole role2 = new IdentityRole("Admin");
                IdentityRole role3 = new IdentityRole("Member");
    
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role2);
                await _roleManager.CreateAsync(role3);
    
                return Ok("added");
            }
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddRole()
            {
                AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync("SuperAdminKamil");
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "SuperAdmin");
                return Ok("added");
            }
    
    
            public IActionResult Login()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
    
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel adminLogin)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }
    
                AppUser appUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(adminLogin.Username);
    
                if (appUser == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "name or password is invalid");
                    return View();
                }
    
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(appUser, adminLogin.Password, false, false);
    
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "name or password is invalid");
                    return View();
                }
    
    
                return RedirectToAction("index","home");
            }
    
            public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
            }
    
            public IActionResult Register()
            {
                return View();
            }
    
    
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel register)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }
    
                AppUser user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(register.Username);
    
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("username", "bele nir user name sitifade olunub");
                    return View();
                }
    
                user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(register.Email);
    
                if (user != null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("email", "bele nir user email sitifade olunub");
                    return View();
                }
    
                user = new AppUser
                {
                    UserName = register.Username,
                    Email = register.Email,
                    Fullname = register.Fullname,
                };
    
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, register.Password);
    
                if (!result.Succeeded)
                {
                    foreach (var err in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Description);
                        return View();
                    }
                }
    
                var roleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Member");
    
                if (!roleresult.Succeeded)
                {
                    foreach (var err in roleresult.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", err.Description);
                        return View();
                    }
                }
    
                return RedirectToAction("login", "account");
            }
    
        }
    }
```